# Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : Any]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift

I found diverses on the Internet but nothing helped me further. I'm a newcomer and I m gonna help you.
I'll get the message:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : Any]' with an index of type 'String'

```
private func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : Any]){
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as UIImage
    let neuesBild = BildUndNotiz(bild: chosenImage, text: "")

    bildUndNotiz += [neuesBild]
    self.Spoonlist.reloadData()

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:
        {self.zeigeViewControllerFürBildUndNotiz(neuesBild)})

}
```

thank you very much

Comment: where is the problem? what line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SWIFT 4 Solution:**

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]  
as? UIImage else {
  return
}

imagePicked.image = image
//dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This for swift 4.2 and higher, for swift 4 `info` is of type `[String : Any]`

Answer (score 3):

This code is out-of-date. The [correct method signature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller#) is now:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

Because you have the wrong method signature, `info` has the wrong type and can't be subscripted by a string.

Comment: OP: And so you should replace your function  definition with the one Rob shows above.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining the error:

`info` is a `[NSObject : Any]` object. So it's a Dictionary which keys are `NSObject` object.

You do `info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]`, but `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` is a String, not a `NSObject`, so you can't do the subscript like this.

That's what is saying the error.

But that's not all, I suppose the Swift version you use is Swift 4, your method of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` shoudln't be called because it hasn't the good signature.
From the doc:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

Not

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : Any])
```

Replace it with the one from the doc.

Answer (score 0):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

This method takes info as swift dictionary of type `[String: Any]`, where the dictionary key is value type.
But you are passing the dictionary as `[NSObject: Any]`, where the key is object or reference type. So basically you are passing wrong argument and also you can not change the delegate method signature of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.